# grep the input file with keyword, then generate new report

Tags: ruby

cat infile

```
abc 123 678
sda 234 345 321
xyz 234 456 678
```

I need `grep` the file for keyword `sda` and report with first and last column.

```
sda has the value of 321
```

If you know bash script, I need a function in ruby as in below bash(awk) script:

```
awk '/sda/{print $1 " has the value of " $NF}' infile
```

Comment: Compare strings? Split on space and only look at the last array element?

Comment: Sure, grep will work too--but if you knew, why'd you ask? Grep, btw, is a compare, just more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
File.open("infile", "r").each_line do |line|
  next unless line =~ /^sda/ # don't process the line unless it starts with "sda"
  entries = line.split(" ")
  var1 = entries.first
  var2 = entries.last
  puts "#{var1} has the value of #{var2}"
end
```

I don't know where you are defining the "sda" matcher.  If it's fixed, you can just put it in there.
If not, you might try grabbing it from commandline arguments.

Comment: looks you get my points, `line =~ /sda/` should be enough. testing the code

Answer (score 1):

```
key, *_, value = line.split
next unless key == 'sda' # or "next if key != 'sda'"
puts your_string
```

Alternatively, you could use a regexp matcher in the beginning to see if the line starts with 'sda' or not.